# Почему скрипт выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

[image: КОД ОШИБКИ]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.*****.net/?logo'
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
token = soup.find('meta', {'name': '_ga'})['content']
data = {
    'login': 'LOGIN',
    'password': 'PASSWD',
    'remember': '1',
    '_token': token,
    }

resp = session.post('https://www.****.net/index.php?r=/users/auth/login', data=data,)
print(resp.text)
```

Нужно с первого url вытащить токен и зайти с этим токеном на второй url. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы прикрепили скриншот ошибки. Так как вы закрыли звездочками url сервиса который парсите, ошибка невоспроизводима

Comment: Скриншот прикрепил)

Comment: @ClickName Как ненавязчиво узнать, что скрывается под * :)